# Check if current URL pattern exist in another language in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, url-pattern

I'm trying to start of my new website in Django with a lot of settings which down the road will be tougher to implement. One of these things is website internationalization, but also url pattern internationalization.

What I am trying to achieve is having urls like this:

```
www.example.com/news                 [en] [news]
www.example.com/en/news              [en] [news]
www.example.com/no/nyheter           [no] [news]
www.example.com/en/top-articles      [en] [top articles]
```

and on every page I visit, I want the website navigation to have a dropdown menu, which contains website languages, and which language is currently selected. Similar to this:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="/en/news" hreflang="en" class="active">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="/no/nyheter" hreflang="no" rel="alternate">Norsk</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now as for changing to another language, is there any way to see **if the current page exists in the language** the users can pick from?

If the current page **does not exist** in the language of choice, I want the user to be returned to the frontpage of the selected language. So the dropdown would look like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="/en/top-articles" hreflang="en" class="active">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="/no" hreflang="no">Norsk</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you creating translation files for each resource or having the content for each resource persisted for each language in the database?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I'm thinking about having translation files, and for content, such as articles, I will create multiple in the database, each for every language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I see you doing this is by setting `django_language` in the user session based on user selection.

Django will handle translation of any text 
 that is specified using `gettext_lazy`.  Your URLs will be generated using Django `url.reverse` function together with `django_language` and other arguments.

Determining if the current page exists in the language the users can pick from will boil down to your implementation.

For example, content models will have a language field make it easy to query for records whose language match `django_language`. If there is no match, a redirect can be made to *language* front page assuming that will always exist.

#### References:

http://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter19.html

Comment: Is there any way to back-track this through templates in Django? So lets say `get_url "en" as url` and if exists it will return the URL? If not, it returns false, and I can validate this in template to output language frontpage instead? Is this possible? I just read through the entired docs on internationalization, but I couldn't find a specific track-back option... as for validating certain urls, such as articles, I am aware that I have to create my own database lookup.

Comment: You should consider writing a custom template tag if you'll like to backtrack urls inside of the template _to the url for the front page_. This is going to be really weird. What I recommend is backtracking in the view function or method. This way you can always redirect the user to the appropriate language front page.

Comment: Good point, maybe I should do that instead. Do you know if gettext allows variables instead of strings? I have a shared header template and I need to pass a head_title variable for each page using that template. Looks cleaner with variables instead of strings when translating through the view of each page.

Comment: Yes gettext allows for using variables.

Comment: Great, I will try out the way you described :)